# Gradient Descent returns NaN values for slope and error

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I'm new to machine learning and am trying to implement gradient descent. The code I have looks like this and has been resulting in NaN values for all parameters:

```
def compute_error_for_line_given_points(b,m,points):
    totalError = 0 #sum of square error formula
    for i in range (0, len(points)):
        x = points[i, 0]
        y = points[i, 1]
        totalError += (y-(m*x + b)) ** 2
    return totalError/ float(len(points))

def step_gradient(b_current, m_current, points, learning_rate):
    #gradient descent
    b_gradient = 0
    m_gradient = 0
    N = float(len(points))
    for i in range(0, len(points)):
        x = points[i, 0]
        y = points[i, 1]
        b_gradient += -(2/N) * (y - (m_current * x + b_current))
        m_gradient += -(2/N) * x * (y - (m_current * x + b_current))
    new_b = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
    new_m = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient) 
    return [new_b,new_m]

def gradient_descent_runner(points, starting_b, starting_m, learning_rate, num_iterations):
    b = starting_b
    m = starting_m
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        b,m = step_gradient(b, m, array(points), learning_rate)
    return [b,m]

def run():
    #Step 1: Collect the data
    points = genfromtxt("C:/Users/mishruti/Downloads/For Linear Regression.csv", delimiter = ",")
    #Step 2: Define our Hyperparameters
    learning_rate = 0.0000001 #how fast the data converge
    #y=mx+b (Slope formule)
    initial_b = 0 # initial y-intercept guess
    initial_m = 0 # initial slope guess
    num_iterations = 4
    print("Starting gradient descent at b = {0}, m = {1}, error = {2}".format(initial_b, initial_m, compute_error_for_line_given_points(initial_b, initial_m, points)))
    print("Running...")
    [b, m] = gradient_descent_runner(points, initial_b, initial_m, learning_rate, num_iterations)
    print("After {0} iterations b = {1}, m = {2}, error = {3}".format(num_iterations, b, m, compute_error_for_line_given_points(b, m, points)))

# main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

A sample from my data set is attached. Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks!

[image: Sample Data Set]

Comment: Since there are only two parameters (m and n), why don't you track their values to see what is happening to them?

Comment: I'm free for sometime. You could attach a link to a colab notebook. I would be happy to debug

Comment: Hi @tritsu, I tried manually calculating the values and am getting positive, definite values but the function returns NaN right after the first iteration. That's what's throwing me off.

Comment: Hi @VijethRai, could you please let me know if you're available today to work along? I'll set something up.

Comment: Yeah I'm free today (indian time). Just copy paste the entire code into google colab and share it. Or you can upload your notebook onto colab and share it if the problem still persists